# Azure Diganostic settings - Category Groups

Tags: azure

Within Azure Resources, specific resources contain a Diagnostic settings page. This can be interacted with using the `Set-AzDiagnosticSetting` [PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-8.0.0).

The module appears to let you be able to alter nearly every single metric on the diagnostic page except the Category Groups.

The module supports enabling the **Categories** under **Logs**, but not the **Category groups**. Does anyone know if that is actually possible to change via PowerShell?

```
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceID $ResourceID -Enabled $true -MetricCategory AllMetrics -Category AuditEvent -Name $EventHubLoggingName -EventHubName $EventHubName -EventHubAuthorizationRuleId $EventHubPath | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot create diagnostic setting with Category groups using either [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-8.0.0) or with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/diagnostic-settings?view=azure-cli-latest) cmdlets.

Alternatively you can use the Azure Management Rest API [Diagnostic Settings - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnostic-settings/create-or-update) to create the Diagnostic settings with Category groups.

I have tested this REST API (by creating `Audit` category group diagnostics settings to the keyvault) it is working fine from my end and I would suggest you to create validate it from your end as well.

**Here is sample output for reference:**

[image]

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/diagnostic-settings/create-or-update#logsettings) for more information about which properties you can to the logs property in the request body.